# Merge multiple data frames with similar names and add a new column indicating origin

Tags: r, dplyr

I have several data frames that I want to merge into one large dataframe. In addition, I want to add a column to this new dataframe that indicates which data frame the data originated from. I did make a rather crude way of doing this:

```
exports_all<- rbind((mutate(Dai15_Dai3_1, sentiment = factor("week1"))),
                    (mutate(Dai15_Dai3_2, sentiment = factor("week2"))),
                    (mutate(Dai15_Dai3_3, sentiment = factor("week3"))),
                    (mutate(Dai15_Dai3_4, sentiment = factor("week4"))),
                    (mutate(Dai15_Dai3_5, sentiment = factor("week5"))),
                    (mutate(Dai15_Dai3_6, sentiment = factor("week6"))),
                    (mutate(Dai15_Dai3_7, sentiment = factor("week7"))))
```

Produces:

```
     Region_ID  Sv_mean  Week
1        10    -64.01115 week1
2        10    -64.96363 week1
3        10    -67.98841 week1
4        13    -66.88734 week2
5        13    -69.79789 week2
6        13    -69.94071 week2
7        15    -66.04855 week3
8        15    -68.31167 week3
9        15    -68.67383 week3
```

I'm trying to find a more elegant way of doing this. The data I used here was broken into 7 weeks, but next years data could be different (also the year before had 12 weeks). I'm trying to find a solution that will not choke up when encountering differing week numbers.

I did make some progress but the only solution I found inserts a column with the dataframe of origin, not exactly what I need.

```
exports_all<- mget(ls(pattern = 'Dai15_Dai3_*')) %>%
  map_df(I, .id = 'Week')
```

Comment: Probably on the right track but I am getting this error message: Error in as_mapper(.f, ...) : argument ".f" is missing, with no default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may have to modify the names of the `list` as `mget` returns a `named` list with the names being the object names.

```
library(dplyr)
mget(ls(pattern = 'Dai15_Dai3_*')) %>% 
  setNames(paste0("Week", seq_along(.))) %>%
  bind_rows(.id = "Week") %>%
  relocate(Week, .after = last_col())
```

If it should replace the substring in the original names

```
library(stringr)
mget(ls(pattern = 'Dai15_Dai3_*')) %>%
  setNames(str_replace(names(.), ".*_(\\d+)$", "Week\\1")) %>% 
  bind_rows(.id = "Week") %>%
  relocate(Week, .after = last_col())
```

NOTE: `bind_rows` is enough as we are not applying any functions in each of the `list` elements (in the OP's code, `I` (identity) was used as a placeholder for `.f`)

Comment: That worked, thank you. One detail though. The new 'week' column is being placed as the first column of the data frame, any way to have it be added as the last column? Not a huge deal if that's more involved.

Comment: @JacksonASwan Just add `%>% relocate(Week, .after = last_col())` at the end